# sudo systemctl start openvpn-server@server.service doesn't want to work

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, systemd, systemctl

I have a problem with the OpenVPN service.

I've already changed the server.conf, sysctl.conf and before.rules settings,

specifically these changes,

```
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret

cipher AES-256-CBC

dh dh2048.pem

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

However, I cannot activate OpenVPN.

I'm following the step by step of this link,

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-20-04-en

Here's the error:

```
● openvpn-server@server.service - OpenVPN service for server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn-server@.service; enabled; vendor >
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-09-15 20>
       Docs: man:openvpn(8)
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
    Process: 90662 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --status /run/openvpn-server/status>
   Main PID: 90662 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Pre-connection initialization successful"
        CPU: 21ms

Sep 15 20:36:11 hydra systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Main process exit>
Sep 15 20:36:11 hydra systemd[1]: openvpn-server@server.service: Failed with result>
```

Thanks to whoever responds.